# Local declaration of tableView hides instance variable?

Tags: objective-c

I understand why I get the warning in the title when I define my own tableView property in my own class and then use a local variable name tableView.

What I want to know is why DON'T I get this warning when I derive my class from UITableViewController, which has it's own tableView property? Does the compiler/editor only look at my class and not the parent class?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you’re implementing a method, parameters/local variables share the same namespace as instance variables. However, they don’t share the same namespace as declared properties, which means that a class can declare a property named `someData` (or inherit it from one of its superclasses), have the backing instance variable with some other name, and the implementation of a method of that class can also have a parameter/local variable named `someData` — the compiler won’t give a warning in that case.

I assume you have a declared property named `tableView` and also an instance variable named `tableView`, the latter being either explicitly declared in the interface or automatically created when synthesizing the property. In that case, if you define a method that takes a parameter named `tableView` or declares a local variable named `tableView`, this local declaration will hide the *instance variable* named `tableView` (but not the property).

In the case of `UITableViewController`, there is no instance variable named `tableView`. There is a declared property named `tableView` which, because it’s in a different namespace, won’t be hidden by a local (variable) declaration.

One easy fix to avoid the compiler warnings is to give a different name to the instance variable. For instance, the instance variable can be named `_tableView`, and the property would still be named `tableView` but synthesized as `@synthesize tableView = _tableView`.

Comment: I only have a property declaration for tableView in my class, e.g. @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
So I'm still missing a piece of the puzzle. I was under the impression @synthesize would instantiate an i-var for tableView.

Comment: And it does indeed. But in the case of UITableViewController, there is no compiler-accessible instance variable named tableView — either they're using _view from UIViewController or adding an instance variable dynamically. You can void the compiler warnings by having an ivar with a different name, e.g. _tableView, and @synthesize tableView = _tableView.

Comment: I’ve expanded my answer to include my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Post the exact code that is generating the warning.

"Local declaration" typically implies that you have something like:

```
- (void) foo {
    int thisIsTheNameOfAnInstanceVariable;
}
```

There are likely other permutations via which you could cause this to happen, though.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure if I'm answering this correctly, but if you want to access variables in the super classes (e.g. UITableView, since your class is deriving form it) you have to use "self." then the variable name form the super class. Whenever you directly call a variables, e.g. 'myVariable', it will only look for local instances.

Comment: Not true;  if you say `foo` and `foo` is an instance variable in the superclass, it'll be accessed directly (barring @private).   `self.foo` is a method call.